# Android java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on GridView 50 Drawables images

Tags: android, gridview

I'm desperate and I don't know what can I do. I have tried many things to fix it and I just always departing OutOfMemory Error. I have try with Universal Image Loader library and many other internet fixes, but I always get this error:

```
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:577)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:775)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1998)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:707)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:542)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:315)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at com.example.nititzart.jigsawpuzzle.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:65)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2431)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1323)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:328)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:281)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.widget.GridView.fillGap(GridView.java:241)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5737)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4878)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
03-13 12:45:05.151: E/AndroidRuntime(6460):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My application have a total of 50 image in a GridView. Every image is a JPG file with 25KB each one. I really need help because now I totally blocked without knowing what else to do.

Comment: Share what you have tried to create & load images in grid.

Comment: you have `outOfMemory` error. In which case, I think you need to check you are you storing images at runtime and using them to be shown. May be you need to compress them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Volley for better & optimized way to implement loading of images

```
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-volley-library-example.html
```